# How to get Hexagon shape from SKPhysicsBody from SpriteKit framework

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am doing iOS app in swift. I want to show layout like Apple Music bubbles. And the below code is working fine to show that layout, but, I want to show Hexagon layout instead of circle bubble.

Can anyone suggest/guide me, how to show that Hexagonal layout instead of circle layout.

In Magnetic Class :

```
 func configure() {

         physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
         physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: { () -> CGRect in
             var frame = self.frame
             frame.size.width = CGFloat(magneticField.minimumRadius)
             frame.origin.x -= frame.size.width / 2
             return frame
         }())
         let strength = Float(max(size.width, size.height))
         let radius = strength.squareRoot() * 100
         magneticField.region = SKRegion(radius: radius)
         magneticField.minimumRadius = radius
         magneticField.strength = strength
         magneticField.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
     }
```

In Node Class :

```
public init(text: String?, image: UIImage?, color: UIColor, radius: CGFloat) {
    super.init(circleOfRadius: radius)

    self.physicsBody = {
        let body = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius + 2)
        body.allowsRotation = false
        body.friction = 0
        body.linearDamping = 3
        return body
    }()
    self.fillColor = .white
    self.strokeColor = .white
    _ = self.sprite
    _ = self.text
    configure(text: text, image: image, color: color)
}
```

Comment: your code does nothing to help us,  you only show a physics body and a magnetic field

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I added Node class code too, can you check, and provide any suggestions to get Hexagonal shape? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

expanding on KnightofDragon's answer, you can calculate the 6 points of a hexagon with the following psuedocode/math:

```
PI =  3.14159
for i in 0..<6 {
    theta = i*2.0*PI / n; // angle to the ith vertex, in radians (not degrees)
    x = radius * cos(theta)
    y = radius * sin(theta)
    vertex = centerPosition.x + x, centerPosition.y + y 
}
```

Comment: you can do Float.pi  and not have to worry about making your own constant, +1 for the help

Comment: Thanks. I stripped this from a C++/openGL project I did two weeks ago, and admittedly didn't put much effort into turning it into Swift.

Comment: I tried to do that way, like following         let lineWidth: CGFloat = 2
        let hexaGonPath = roundedPolygonPath(rect: rectFrame, lineWidth: lineWidth, sides: 6, cornerRadius: 10, rotationOffset: CGFloat(M_PI / 2.0)) as! CGPath
But, its getting BAD EXCESS

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use a different initializer.  You are using `super.init(circleOfRadius: radius)`  To make a hexagon, just use `super.init(path path:CGPath)`  Where path is a CGPath in the shape of a hexagon.  (CGPath is simple to understand,  just create it with 6 points in the shape of a hexagon, however large you need it)  You can then take this path and give it to the physics body by doing `let body = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom:path)`

On a personal note,  you may want to cut back on using closures the way you are doing it. (`let physicsBody = {...}()`)  They are not guaranteed to fire immediately and could cause a concurrency problem.  A better way to right it would be to do it in an if let statement:

```
if let body = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius + 2)
{        
    body.allowsRotation = false
    body.friction = 0
    body.linearDamping = 3
    self.physicsBody = body
}
```

Comment: On your aside: immediately invoked closures have nothing to do with concurrency, and are indeed invoked immediately. `let foo = {...}()` has the same effect as `let foo = someFunc()`, just without the body of `someFunc` needing to be defined elsewhere.

Comment: @rickster, I am going to have to go through some of my code, but I believe I ran into problems when doing something like this on background threads was causing my closures to crash because the closure was expecting an object that not longer existed

Comment: I tried to do that way, like following         let lineWidth: CGFloat = 2
        let hexaGonPath = roundedPolygonPath(rect: rectFrame, lineWidth: lineWidth, sides: 6, cornerRadius: 10, rotationOffset: CGFloat(M_PI / 2.0)) as! CGPath
But, its getting BAD EXCESS

Comment: What is a roundedPolygonPath? It is not returning a valid CGPath